# JSON unmarshalling of array of objects crashes with nil map

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have the following minimal reproduction, when this code runs it throws an exception at `basicMap[key] = value` because `assignment to entry in nil map`, however it only does this when the type is `[]CustomMap` - when I use a `CustomMap` for a single item, it works just fine.

Is there a way of unmarshalling arrays of custom objects in go?

```
package main

import "encoding/json"

type CustomMap map[string]any

type Payload struct {
    Items []CustomMap `json:"items"`
}

func mapToBasicMap(basicMap CustomMap, aMap map[string]any) {
    for key, value := range aMap {
        basicMap[key] = value
    }
}

func (this CustomMap) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var aMap map[string]any = make(map[string]any)
    json.Unmarshal(data, &aMap)
    mapToBasicMap(this, aMap)
    return nil
}
func main() {
    payload := Payload{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"items\":[{\"item1\": 1}]}"), &payload)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unmarshal should have a pointer receiver. Make the target map before using assigning to its values.

```
func (this *CustomMap) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var aMap map[string]any = make(map[string]any)
    json.Unmarshal(data, &aMap)
    *this = make(CustomMap)
    mapToBasicMap(*this, aMap)
    return nil
}
```

A different fix is to delete method CustomMap.UnmarshalJSON

Comment: Thanks! I'm annoyed it's that simple :facepalm: - new to go, any explanation of why it works for individual CustomMap but not arrays?

Comment: Because the map type is actually a `*hmap` under the hood. The underlying implementation of a slice is a struct. So when you use a value receiver, it copies the slice struct, while when you use a map type as a value receiver, it is still a pointer.
The reason this works is that you would like the address of CustomMap to change value there. If you use a value receiver, your local variable named `this` is pointing at the CustomMap within the payload. but when you use a value receiver and assign, you are just changing where the local variable is pointing at, not the content itself.